# Cramer-Rao lower bound question for geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

So I am doing some self studying in preparation for the Statistical Inference course next semester.  I stumbled upon this question which is:

> If you have a random sample of size $n$ from a geometric distribution with a mean of $1/p,$ find the Cramer-Rao lower bound for the variance of an unbiased estimator of $p.$

Here is my attempt so far

We know that if $T$ is an unbiased estimator of $\tau(\theta)$, if the Cramer-Rao lower bound, based on a random sample  is:

$$\operatorname{Var}(T) \ge \frac{[\tau'(\theta)]^2}{n\operatorname E \left[\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(X;\theta)\right)^2\right]}$$

Solving for $\tau(\theta)$

$$\tau(\theta) = p$$

$$\tau'(\theta) = 1$$

$$[\tau'(\theta)]^2 = 1$$

Solving for $f(x;\theta)$

$$f(x;\theta) = p(1-p)^{x-1}$$

$$\ln f(x;\theta) = \ln p  + (x-1) \ln(1-p) = \ln p + x\ln(1-p) - \ln(1-p)$$

$$\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial p } = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{x-1}{1-p}$$

I don't know what to do next.  Please help!

Comment: "Solving for" is one of those phrases used as a catch-all by those who don't know what words to use. This is an instance of that. There is also a correct way to use the term.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Hardy for my clumsy wording.  If you can correct my wording it would be appreciated!

Comment: The only thing that is left to do is to calculate the expectation of the derivative of the log likelihood squared. And the Cramer Rao bound you gave is wrong, the square must be inside the expectation, NOT outside.

Comment: @Shashi I think I fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would have to consider the square of your last expression, and evaluate that expression for $x=X$ (that is, evaluate at the r.v. $X$). Finally, you would have to take expectation, using the fact that $X$ has the mentioned geometric distribution. That is:

$$E\left[\left(\frac1p-\frac{X-1}{1-p}\right)^2\right]=E\left[\left(\frac{1-pX}{p(1-p)}\right)^2\right]=\frac1{p^2(1-p)^2}E\left(1-2pX+p^2X^2\right)=\cdots$$
for which you will have to know which is $E(X^2)$ (you already know that $E(X)=\tfrac1p$).

Nevertheless, there's an equivalent expression that you get by changing the denominator by
$$-nE\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}\ln f(X;\theta)\right),$$
provided this second derivative exists. This alternative formula gives simpler calculations many times, not having to take expectation of any square (and I find it works fine in this case).

Comment: To calculate $E(X^2)$, I know that $E(X^2) = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$.  So $E(X^2) = \left(\frac{1-p}{p^2}\right) + (\frac{1}{p})^2$?

Comment: Yes. It's a good strategy if you already know the mean and the variance.

Comment: How would you calculate the $E(X^2)$ if you don't do it that way?  Would you have to use the moment generating function?

Comment: In this case, I would. It seems much easier than doing the direct calculation by summing $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2 \cdot p (1-p)^{x-1}.$$

Comment: I worked it out to be $\frac{1}{n \left(\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\right)}$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I got the first $p$ squared.

Comment: Oh yeah of course!  I somehow took of the square for no reason. Thank you!